# Run Spring Shell Command after starte Docker Image

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, github-actions, spring-shell

I use a Github Action to start a Spring Boot image on a vServer. This Spring Boot application contains the Spring Shell Component and I can run my `init-users` command.

When I start the image locally or manually on the vServer, the shell is available.

```bash
$ docker run -it -p 8082:8080 repo/my-api
$ ...
$ shell:>
```

The following is an example of the docker commads in the GitHub Action.

```bash
script: |
    docker stop $(docker container ls  | grep 'repo/my-api' | awk '{print $1}')
    docker run -it -p 8002:8080 8080 repo/my-api:1.2.3
    # call init-users ?
```

How can the call to run `init-users` after starting the image look like?

It is not an option to define the shell command in the Dockerfile because I only want to run `init-users` during deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You should familirize yourself with [Github Actions components](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/understanding-github-actions#the-components-of-github-actions)

Try to understand steps. A step is an individual task that can run commands in a job
Example with bash

```
steps:
  - name: Display the path
    run: echo $PATH
    shell: bash
```